# Where do exchanges store the user's money?

Tags: exchanges, payment, bitcoin-core-accounts, kraken

For example if I deposit money to **Kraken** with my credit card and I do Not buy any coin they just stay in my user account there, since they are withdrawn from my bank account are the money kept in the Kraken's bank account or ?

This question may also be asked for any web application/site that accepts deposits to user accounts ..

Answer (score 1):

It's up to Kraken what they do with the money on deposit with them, though most likely they pool it in bank accounts or other secure liquid investments belonging to the company.  The exact details might be proprietary.

When you buy some coins, the amount you spent will be deducted from your user account, and credited to the account of whoever sold you the coins (minus commissions), but the actual money stays in Kraken's own accounts until the seller withdraws money from her account.  Then Kraken will transfer money from their bank account to hers.